# Take keys from another property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a React component that receives some data via props and I want to add safe property access.

I've already tried:

```
type Props = {
  items?: any[]; // not really sure is type "any"
  bindValue?: keyof Props['items'];
  bindLabel?: keyof Props['items'];
}
```

```
const dynamicData = [{ id: 1, text: 'test' }, { id: 2, text: 'test 2' }];

<Select items={dynamicData} bindLabel="text" bindValue="id"/>

==================== Select Component =============================

type Props = {
  items?: any[]; // should match the keys of dynamicData
  bindLabel?: string; // key of items
  bindValue?: string; // type of key of items
}

const Select: FC<Props> = ({ items, bindValue, bindLabel }) => {
   return <></>;
}

export default Select;
```

```
* it should pass
<Select items={dynamicData} bindLabel="text" bindValue="id"/>

* it should fail
<Select items={dynamicData} bindLabel="xx" bindValue="MM"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the item type through generic parameter:

```
type Props<T> = {
  items?: T[];
  bindValue?: keyof T;
  bindLabel?: keyof T;
}

function Select<T>({ items, bindValue, bindLabel }: Props<T>) {
  return <></>;
}
```